# Mocking functions called inside then() with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test this function

```
const handleSave = () => {
    const cveIds = cveList.map(item => item.id);
    return setCveStatus({
        status_id: parseInt(statusId),
        cve: cveIds,
        status_text: justification
    })
    .then(() => !checkboxState && setSystemCveStatus({ cve: cveIds }))
    .then(updateRef);
};
```

which calls 2 functions *setCveStatus* and *setSystemCveStatus* which I am mocking

```
const setCveStatusMock = jest.fn(parameters => new Promise(resolve => resolve(parameters)));
const setSystemCveStatusMock = jest.fn(parameters => new Promise(resolve => resolve(parameters)));

deps.setCveStatus = setCveStatusMock;
deps.setSystemCveStatus = setSystemCveStatusMock;
```

and testing what are they called with

```
expect(setCveStatusMock).toBeCalledWith({
    status_id: 3,
    status_text: 'new',
    cve: ['CVE-2020-0001']
});

expect(setSystemCveStatusMock).toBeCalledWith({
    cve: ['CVE-2020-0001']
});
```

But the second expect fails, even though it shouldn't have.
How can I mock and test functions called inside .then()?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `handleSave()` in your tests?

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this elegantly is with [asyncFn](https://github.com/team-igniter-from-houston-inc/async-fn/blob/master/packages/jest/README.md).

With that instead of:

```js
const setCveStatusMock = jest.fn(parameters => new Promise(resolve => resolve(parameters)));

// ...

expect(setSystemCveStatusMock).toBeCalledWith({
    cve: ['CVE-2020-0001']
});
```

you can

```js
import asyncFn from '@asyncFn/jest';
const setCveStatusMock = asyncFn();

// ...

// Resolve the call for setCveStatusMock and await for anything that happens as a result of that.
await setCveStatusMock.resolve();

// ...

expect(setSystemCveStatusMock).toBeCalledWith({
    cve: ['CVE-2020-0001']
});
```

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors.